# Prompt the user for an index - 2D array - output the array element given by the index - java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, output, row, command-prompt

I'm very new to Java and have no idea what I'm doing. How can I prompt the user for an index for a 2D array in the format 'ab' (the value of a is row number and the value of b is column number) and output the array element given by the index? For example, if the use enters "00" it
should output '3'.
Any help would be appreciated. Please keep in mind that I'm not allowed to use array list.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise23 {
 public static void main(String[]args) {
  
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  int row = 3;
  int col = 4;
  int[][] array = new int[row][col];
  System.out.println("Enter the index: ");
  int index=scanner.nextInt();
  String sIndex= String.format("%2d", index);
  String quit = "quit";
  
  if(sIndex!=quit){
   
    array[0][0] =3;
    array[0][1] =0;
    array[0][2] =0;
    array[0][3] =4;
    
    array[1][0] =2;
    array[1][1] =8;
    array[1][2] =0;
    array[1][3] =0;
    
    array[2][0] =1;
    array[2][1] =1;
    array[2][2] =0;
    array[2][3] =1;
    

    
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
     for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
      System.out.print(array[i][j]);
     }
     System.out.println("");
    }
   
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Comment: Use your text book, and/or use your favourite search engine to find the tutorials for how to prompt the user for an integer and how to retrieve an element from a 2D array. It is out there. BTW, if the user enters 114, is that row 1 column 14 or row 11 column 4?

Comment: The integer needs to have 2 digits, one for row and the other for the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. I would do:

```
        if (sIndex.length() == 2) {
            int selectedRow = Character.getNumericValue(sIndex.charAt(0));
            int selectedColumn = Character.getNumericValue(sIndex.charAt(1));
            // do your stuff
        }
```

You will probably want to add an else part that issues an error message.

If the user is nasty and enters -1, the length will be 2, and I don’t know what the above code will do, certainly nothing meaningful.

Comment: I suspect you are having a problem if the user types 00 or 02. Since array indices are 0-based, s/he will expect this to work. Try if `String.format("%02d", index);` is better.